# Very little water flow after fixing a leak at my parents' house

Tags: plumbing, leak, water-pressure

My parents were recently notified that their water line had a slow leak, so they asked if I could come fix it. They paid for someone to locate the leak, I dug to the pipe, found the leak and replaced the section of pipe. But when we turned the water supply line back on, there is very little water flow to the house. Their water pressure was fine before the "fix", so I don't think it's mineral build up. The only thing I can think of would be a rock getting into the supply line and getting lodged somewhere. Any help or wisdom would be appreciated.

Comment: I would check the first valve or elbow after the fix.  How was the fix done?  If solder was used then excess solder has caused problems like this before.

Comment: It's all 1 1/2 inch pvc. A 45° joint had a hairline crack in it, so I had to replace that joint and then used a compression coupling over the straight pipes. After the water pressure didn't come back, I took the compression coupling back off and put a snake up to see if I could feel any obstructions. There felt like some resistence about 15' up the line, but not much. Do you think I should dig there and see if there's a clog? Or is there a better way to check that you know of?

Comment: Also, I greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: With the water off I might try to see if blowing air from the house will loosen the clog.  Keep the air pressure below 80 pounds, 40 or 50 should be plenty.  Can buy cheap air valves that fix on outdoor faucets.  An air compressor can be rented.  If a neighbour house is close, same idea but with a garden hose.

Comment: My parents' sprinkler system has a port for attaching a compressor-it's what they used when they found the leaks location-would that work the same, or is it better to go through the outdoor faucet?

Comment: Also, these might be dumb questions, but should I have the water main turned off when I blow air through the line? Also, should I have the pipe assembled or left open (where I have the slip fitting)?

Comment: You want the pipe open up so any clog will come out.  I do imagine you do this with the main turned off so it is easier to do.  I think the outside faucet be best, turn off the valve going to the sprinklers.  The less piping to blow though the better.  I would also isolate/turn off the valves to the hot water tank.